# Angular - Component data binding not working the 2nd time

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm having trouble fixing a bug where the data binding is not working on my second `app-orders-list-section`.

Here is the .html for the parent `app-orders-list`:

```
<div class="list-container">
    <label class="list-header" *ngIf="filteredSlotsOrders.length > 0" style="margin-top: 1.625rem;">DELIVERY SLOTS ORDERS</label>
    <div style="height: 50vh; overflow-y: scroll;" *ngIf="filteredSlotsOrders.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let date of timelinesWithSlots">
            <app-orders-list-section
                [slotsOrders]="filteredSlotsOrders"
                [timeline]="date"
                [isDeliverySlotsActive]="true"
                [searchTerm]="searchTerm"
            ></app-orders-list-section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="list-container">
    <label class="list-header" *ngIf="filteredNoSlotsOrders.length > 0" style="margin-top: 2.438rem;">ORDERS WITHOUT SLOTS</label>
    <div style="height: 50vh; overflow-y: scroll;" *ngIf="filteredNoSlotsOrders.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let date of timelinesWithNoSlots">
            <app-orders-list-section
                [noSlotsOrders]="filteredNoSlotsOrders"
                [timeline]="date"
                [isDeliverySlotsActive]="false"
                [searchTerm]="searchTerm"
            ></app-orders-list-section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the corresponding .ts file for `app-orders-list`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-orders-list',
    templateUrl: './orders-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./orders-list.component.css'],
})
export class OrdersListComponent implements OnChanges{
    
    @Input() ordersWithSlots: Order[] = [];
    @Input() ordersWithNoSlots: Order[] = [];
    @Input() timelinesWithSlots: string[] = [];
    @Input() timelinesWithNoSlots: string[] = [];
    @Input() isDeliverySlotsActive: boolean;
    @Input() searchTerm: string;
    filteredSlotsOrders: Order[] = [];
    filteredNoSlotsOrders: Order[] = []

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        // keep orders updated on changes
        if(changes.ordersWithSlots){
            if(changes.ordersWithSlots.currentValue != changes.ordersWithSlots.previousValue){
                this.filteredSlotsOrders = this.ordersWithSlots;
            }
        }
        if(changes.ordersWithNoSlots){
            if(changes.ordersWithNoSlots.currentValue != changes.ordersWithNoSlots.previousValue){
                this.filteredNoSlotsOrders = this.ordersWithNoSlots;
            }
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
```

The data originates from the smart component, parent to `app-orders-list`. It's where the data flux begins and it is set like this, on `ngOnInit()`:

```
/* this is executed periodically with timer() */
getInitialPendingTabOrders(){
        this.apiManager.fetchShopOrders(this.currentPendingTabOrdersCount, "status=PENDING&status=FULFILLED").subscribe(orders => {
            const loadedOrders: OrdersList = orders;
            this.nextSetOfPendingTabOrdersUrl = orders.next;
            // slots
            this.loadedSlotsPendingOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(loadedOrders["results"], OrderStatus.PENDING, true);
            this.loadedSlotsProcessedOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(loadedOrders["results"], OrderStatus.PROCESSED, true);
            this.loadedSlotsPendingOrders.push(...this.loadedSlotsProcessedOrders);
            this.pendingSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedSlotsPendingOrders);
            // no slots
            this.loadedNoSlotsPendingOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(loadedOrders["results"], OrderStatus.PENDING, false);
            this.loadedNoSlotsProcessedOrders = this.ordersService.filterOrders(loadedOrders["results"], OrderStatus.PROCESSED, false);
            this.loadedNoSlotsPendingOrders.push(...this.loadedNoSlotsProcessedOrders);
            this.pendingNoSlotsOrderTimelines = this.ordersService.createTimelines(this.loadedNoSlotsPendingOrders);
            this.pendingNoSlotsOrderTimelines.reverse();
        })
}
```

And for the smart component .html:

```
 <app-orders-list
     [ordersWithSlots]="loadedSlotsPendingOrders"
     [ordersWithNoSlots]="loadedNoSlotsPendingOrders"
     [timelinesWithSlots]="pendingSlotsOrderTimelines"
     [timelinesWithNoSlots]="pendingNoSlotsOrderTimelines"
     [isDeliverySlotsActive]="isDeliverySlotsActive"
     [searchTerm]="searchTerm"
></app-orders-list>
```

For the first `app-orders-list-section`, the bindings are working correctly. However, in the second container, the bindings in `app-orders-list-section` come up empty.

This is my .ts for the `app-orders-list-section` component:

```
@Input() timeline: string;
@Input() slotsOrders: Order[] = [];
@Input() noSlotsOrders: Order[] = [];
@Input() isDeliverySlotsActive: boolean;
@Input() searchTerm: string;
sectionOrders: Order[] = [];

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createSectionOrders();
    this.sortOrders();
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(this.isDeliverySlotsActive) // prints always true
    if(changes.slotsOrders){
        console.log("hello") // this prints!
        if(changes.slotsOrders.currentValue != changes.slotsOrders.previousValue){
            this.createSectionOrders();
            this.sortOrders();
        }
    }
    if(changes.noSlotsOrders){
        console.log("hello") // this doesn't print!
        if(changes.noSlotsOrders.currentValue != changes.noSlotsOrders.previousValue){
            this.createSectionOrders();
            this.sortOrders();
        }
    }
}
...
```

How come the changes are being detected for `slotsOrders` (I can print the data) but are not being detected for `noSlotsOrders`? Even if I try to print `isDeliverySlotsActive`, the result will always be true, even if for the second container I want this field to be set to `false`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a good guess as to why this is occurring. The change will only occur if `filteredNoSlotsOrders` is assigned a new location in memory in your parent component and I bet this is not happening. For Angular Change detection to occur for Array and Object types, they have to have a new location in memory.

Instead of:

```
const newOrder = {};
this.filteredNoSlotsOrders.push(newOrder);
```

Do:

```
const newOrder = {};
this.filteredNoSlotsOrders = [...this.filteredNoSlotsOrders, newOrder];
```

When you're removing data from the array, use `filter`. In essence, every time `filteredNoSlotsOrders` changes, change it immutably (assign it to a new array at a new location in memory).

If you can show the parent component of every time `filteredNoSlotsOrders` changes, I can help you do it immutably.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. You might be on to something as I am indeed using `push()`  in the smart component where the data flux begins. I updated my question in the meantime!

Comment: I guess my question would be, how come the first array `filteredSlotsOrders` is being the detected while `filteredNoSlotsOrders` is not? Isn't the process the same for both the way I have it?

Comment: Are you sure this line runs? `this.filteredNoSlotsOrders = this.ordersWithNoSlots;`.

Comment: Yeah. I tried printing and it is called 2 times. First print is empty while the second print shows the orders.

Comment: I may have potentially found the source of the bug. `this.pendingNoSlotsOrderTimelines` is printing empty on the smart component, when it should have data inside. This array contains the timelines for each grouping/section of orders. Down the line I check in each section if an order corresponds to that section timeline. Of course, if there is no timeline for the order to associate to, it won't be displayed. I'll keep you posted if this is actually the cause. Meanwhile, do I actually need to save each `Input()` data in a new separate field in the component, and pass this new field down?

Comment: For arrays and objects bound to inputs, change them immutably (new location in memory) in the parent component so change detection takes place for them.